# turtlebot bringup android

Tags: turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[there's a question about this by ftrujillo on 27 oct 2013 but there's no answer. so i decided to bring this up again]

hello guys

I have a problem when bringing up the turtlebot. (just a warning)

after launching:

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal_with_appmanager.launch

the warning is:

[WARN] [WallTime: 1382834834.456361] Gateway : uuid's disabled, using possibly non-unique name [turtlebot]

I am using hydro as ROS version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise.

I have been looking for this problem in the ROS answers and in the web but I cannot find nothing.

Then, some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174939/turtlebot-bringup-android/) by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is just a warning from app manager system underneath on turtlebot software. Don't worry about it. It would not cause any problem.

If you really want to eliminate the warning, you can configure [this args in minimal_with_appmanager.launch](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/hydro/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal_with_appmanager.launch#L35).

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on 2014-06-25**:
I'm just worried that it'l affect the communication process. thank you so much for your time to reply. cheers

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-06-29**:
It's only important to have unique id's (uuids) applied to the app manager if you are doing multi-robot rocon concerts where you can have namespace clashes.

**Comment by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on 2014-07-01**:
thanks daniel. let's say there's a need to set the uuids, any guidance on how do i go about doing it?